# Street mapping with Champlain

Tags: python, maps

i'm developing a Gtk Program with Python. I have to display a map and some nodes on this map, which walking around on streets. To achieve this I am using libchamplain.

Displaying the map was quite easy. But is there a way to check if a Coordinate (lat, lon) points on a street? Or any other solution to put some walking markers on the map?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I created a PathLayer and calculated a very, very simple route for a randomly chosen Point on the Map based on [this](https://github.com/F6F/SimpleOsmRouter) algorithm. Then i use Object to print that Point on the route. Every second the Point removes and get plotted on the next position.